# Field calculating sequential numbers based on geographic location (WE_NS Diagonal) in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, spatial-sort, sequential

I am using ArcMap.

I am looking for a script that I can use to field calculate sequential numbers based on the geographic location of the center of polygons. For example, let's say I have 50 parcels on a map, and I want to label them 1 through 50 from West to East/North to South configuration.

Anyone know a script for this?

I've seen scripts for just West/East and North/South, but haven't found one that incorporates both directions (diagonal).

Comment: I think this question needs both illustrate the spatial sort order you are after and your code attempt at achieving it.